# How to get _.pick functionality in lodash version 4

Tags: javascript, lodash

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727745/632292), shown below, is now broken in lodash v4 as far as I can tell.

```
var thing = {
  "a": 123,
  "b": 456,
  "abc": 6789
};

var result = _.pick(thing, function(value, key) {
  return _.startsWith(key, "a");
});

console.log(result.abc) // 6789
console.log(result.b)   // undefined
```

How do you do this in version 4 of lodash?

Answer (score 2):

## Update (08. February)

Since v4.0.1, _.omitBy and _.pickBy now provide a key param to the predicate. Therefore, the correct answer now is:

Use `_.pickBy(object, [predicate=_.identity])`

## Original Answer

Starting with v4, some methods have been split. For Example, _.pick() has been split into `_.pick(array, [props])` and `_.pickBy(object, [predicate=_.identity])`

My first approach was trying this `_.pickBy()` method. Unfortunately all `...By()` methods are only passed the value as the first argument. They won't get the key or the collection passed. That's why it does not work by simply switching from `_.pick()` to `_.pickBy()`.

However, you can do it like this:

```
var thing = {
  "a": 123,
  "b": 456,
  "abc": 6789
};

var result = _.pick(thing, _(thing).keys().filter(function(key) {
  return _.startsWith(key, "a");
}).value());

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yup I tried the same thing, using _.pick and _.pickBy chaining - without success. I'll give you one for ingenuity - but can't really accept as an elegant answer. To my mind they've actually removed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, there is not documented that [_.startsWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#startsWith)  has been removed from Lodash.

One way or another, how about parsing the first character of the key?

```
var result = _.pick(thing, function(value, key) {
  return key[0] == "a";
});
```

Comment: _.pick() in v4 does no longer accept a predicate. That's what _.pickBy is now doing. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thing = {
  "a": 123,
  "b": 456,
  "abc": 6789
};

_.pick(object, arrayOfProperties)
_.pick(thing,["a","b"])={"a":123,"b":456}
```

this method is very useful when you work with rest API. when you create an object from parsing **req.body**  this is how we create the object.

```
router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    age: req.body.age
  });});
```

as you see this is headache and looks ugly. Instead

```
const user=new User(_.pick(req.body,["name","email","password","age"]))
```