# Filtering object by keys in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I wrote the function below to return all keys in an object that match a specific pattern. It seems really round-about because there's no filter function in lodash for objects, when you use it all keys are lost. Is this the only way to filter an objects keys using lodash?

```
export function keysThatMatch (pattern) {
  return (data) => {
    let x = _.chain(data)
    .mapValues((value, key) => {
      return [{
        key: key,
        value: value
      }]
    })
    .values()
    .filter(data => {
      return data[0].key.match(pattern)
    })
    .zipWith(data => {
      let tmp = {}
      tmp[data[0].key] = data[0].value
      return tmp
    })
    .value()
    return _.extend.apply(null, x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter keys of an object with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726830/how-to-filter-keys-of-an-object-with-lodash)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need lodash for this, I would just use `Object.keys`, filter for matches then reduce back down to an object like this (untested, but should work):

```
export function keysThatMatch (pattern) {
  return (data) => {
    return Object.keys(data).filter((key) => {
      return key.match(pattern);
    }).reduce((obj, curKey) => {
      obj[curKey] = data[curKey];
      return obj;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, Thanks!

Comment: Although this is possible with plain js, with es6 I guess we don't need lodash or underscore at all :)

Comment: @WitVault we are definitely getting much closer!

Comment: @RobM. does it also reproduce the exact same behavior as lodash's  "keysIn" function?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `pickBy` from lodash to do this. (https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy)

This example returns an object with keys that start with 'a'

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3, 'aa': 5};

o2 = _.pickBy(object, function(v, k) {
    return k[0] === 'a';
});

o2 === {"a":1,"aa":5}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for an answer that would "filter" an object but would return an object instead. This worked out perfectly

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, the question raised was how to do it with lodash, not if it can be done without it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a succinct way to do this with lodash - [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) and [set()](https://lodash.com/docs#set) are your friends.

```
_.reduce(data, (result, value, key) => key.match(pattern) ? 
  _.set(result, key, value) : result, {});
```