# How to return an object only with keys that have a number value?

Tags: javascript

I have the following Object

```
{date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370, num2: NaN, num3: 100, category: "C"}
```

I would my output to be

```
{num: 370, num3: 100}
```

Removing date_created, num2, and category ideally it would remove also anything that is null or undefined in the value

Comment: But date_created is a number. That aside, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726830/how-to-filter-keys-of-an-object-with-lodash

Comment: @jarmod that's fine if he's already using lodash for something else. But I wouldn't advise anyone to include a library for a such simple task

Comment: You want to remove `date_created`, `num2` and `category` irrespective of their value and in addition to those, any key with null or undefined value? It's not exactly clear

Comment: @CristianTraìna agreed, you can solve this readily in native JavaScript these days.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !isNaN(obj[key]))
```

```js
let obj = {
  date_created: 1546293600000,
  num: 370,
  num2: NaN,
  num3: 100,
  category: "C"
}

let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !isNaN(obj[key]))
let newObj = {}
keys.forEach(key => newObj[key] = obj[key])
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to filter out all the `NaN` values (Not A Number, so also strings, objects, etc). Then re-map the keys to get the values:

```js
const obj = {date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370, num2: NaN, num3: 100, category: "C"}

const newObj = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(key => !isNaN(obj[key]))
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = obj[key];
    return acc;
  }, {});

  
console.log(newObj);
```

In your example you filtered out `date_created` but what's your rationale?

Comment: You can loop only once by filtering within the reduce

Comment: Personal opinion, but I find this format more readable. In this way you know exactly what you're filtering out, and you can easily chain a new `filter` or a `map`. Obviously it's not performance-oriented

Comment: Sometimes beauty > performance. I agree that it is more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) property and a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var myObject = {
  date_created: 1546293600000,
  num: 370,
  num2: NaN,
  num3: 100,
  category: "C"
};

var newObject = Object.keys(myObject)
.filter(key => {
  return !isNaN(myObject[key]);
}).reduce((output, key) => {
  output[key] = obj[key];
  return output;
}, {});
```

In regards to the "date_created" property, you could add something like this:

Ignore all properties that have "date" in their names, even if their values are numbers.

```
var newObject = Object.keys(myObject)
.filter(key => {
  if (key.includes("date")) return false;
  return !isNaN(myObject[key]);
}).reduce((output, key) => {
  output[key] = obj[key];
  return output;
}, {});
```

Comment: You can also use `Object.values()` to check the values directly. Be aware NaN is also of type number

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reduce function

```
function getNumbersObj(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      newObj[key] = value
    }
    return newObj
  }, {})
}
```

Edit: for `date_created` which is a number, you'd could explicitly filter out the key

```
function getNumbersObj(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'number' && key !== 'date_created') {
      newObj[key] = value
    }
    return newObj
  }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop through with filter and return only numbers

```js
 const objects = {
    date_created: 1546293600000,
    num: 370,
    num2: NaN,
    num3: 100,
    category: 'C'
    }

    let newObj = Object.keys(objects).filter( key => 
    !isNaN(key)) 
    
    console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution from efficiency point of view but here is a solution:

```js
const originalObj = {
  date_created: 1546293600000,
  num: 370,
  num2: NaN,
  num3: 100,
  category: "C"
}

const objWithUndefined ={
  date_created: 1546293600000,
  num: 370,
  num2: NaN,
  num3: undefined,
  category: "C"
}
const objWithNull ={
  date_created: 1546293600000,
  num: null,
  num2: NaN,
  num3: 100,
  category: "C"
}

function modifyObject(original) {
  let newObj = Object.assign({}, original);

  delete newObj.date_created;
  delete newObj.num2;
  delete newObj.category;
  
  for (var prop in newObj) {
    if (newObj[prop] == undefined || newObj[prop] == null) {
      delete newObj[prop]

    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

console.log("original: " + JSON.stringify(modifyObject(originalObj), null, 2));
console.log("objWithUndefined: " + JSON.stringify(modifyObject(objWithUndefined), null, 2));
console.log("objWithNull: " + JSON.stringify(modifyObject(objWithNull), null, 2));
```